Will I be restricted from asking questions on a website if my posts receive no votes but are answered?
If I ask a question that no one votes for or against, but someone answers it, will I eventually be unable to ask questions on that website?

By "that website", do you mean the physics site? Or any one of the Stack Exchange sites? Or something else?

Don't worry you won't. People often forget upvoting questions. But that doesn't necessarily mean your questions are poor if they aren't really.

@Proscionexium "People often forget upvoting questions" I completely disagree. It is too easy for questions to receive upvotes. There are many egregious questions that should not have received upvotes that are still upvoted. By "egregious questions" I don't simply mean poorly-worded questions or questions with an easily-found answer. I mean homework dumps and AI-generated nonsense, i.e. the kind of question that should be closed and deleted as soon as possible.

To make things worse, some users go around upvoting every single negatively-scored question.

If all of your questions have zero score, but none are closed or deleted, then you still have a positive question record.  Zero-score questions with no answers may eventually be deleted (on a timescale of a year or so), but zero-score questions with answers are preserved.
